# Group of groups in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have a table `tbl` with the following data:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| A | 3 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 1 |
| C | 2 |
| C | 3 |

**Desired result**

I want to group together the items in col1 who have the same set of values in col2.

E.g.

| list1 | list2 |
| --- | --- |
| A,C | 1 |
| A,C | 2 |
| A,C | 3 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 2 |

**Current result**

I have written some SQL to do this, however, my end result gives me only a single row per group of col1.

| list1 | list2 |
| --- | --- |
| B | 1, 2 |
| A, C | 1, 2, 3 |

```sql
select listagg(col1, ', ') set1, la as set2
from (
    select LISTAGG(t.col2, ', ') la, t.col1
    from tbl t
    GROUP BY t.col1
    )
GROUP BY la
```

**DDL**

```sql
 CREATE TABLE "TBL" 
   (    "COL1" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
        "COL2" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
   );
INSERT INTO TBL VALUES ('A','1');
INSERT INTO TBL VALUES ('A','2');
INSERT INTO TBL VALUES ('A','3');
INSERT INTO TBL VALUES ('B','1');
INSERT INTO TBL VALUES ('B','2');
INSERT INTO TBL VALUES ('C','1');
INSERT INTO TBL VALUES ('C','2');
INSERT INTO TBL VALUES ('C','3');
```

Comment: So what output do you want? If you don't want `col2` aggregated into a delimited list then... why are you doing that?

Comment: Can you create a sqldiddle which reproduces your problem? I get an error saying that the `within` keyword is missing from your query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not very efficient on large data set, but works on your example:

```
    with data(col1, col2) as (
        select 'A', 1 from dual union all
        select 'A', 2 from dual union all
        select 'A', 3 from dual union all
        select 'B', 1 from dual union all
        select 'B', 2 from dual union all
        select 'C', 1 from dual union all
        select 'C', 2 from dual union all
        select 'C', 3 from dual 
    )
    select cols1, regexp_substr(col2s, '\d+', 1, level) as col2
    from (
        select listagg(col1, ',') within group(order by col1) as cols1, col2s
        from (
            select col1, listagg(col2,',') within group(order by col2) as col2s 
            from data
            group by col1
        )
        group by col2s
    )
    connect by level <= regexp_count(col2s, '\d+')
        and prior cols1 = cols1
        and prior sys_guid() is not null
    ;


A,C 1
A,C 2
A,C 3
B   1
B   2
```

Or with listagg() over(partition) version:

```
select distinct listagg(distinct col1, ',') within group(order by col1) over(partition by col2s)  as col1s, 
    col2s, col2
from (
    select col1, 
        listagg(col2,',') within group(order by col2)
        over(partition by col1)  as col2s,
        col2
    from data
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `LISTAGG` twice, once as an analytic function and then as a aggregation function:

```sql
SELECT LISTAGG(col1, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col1) AS col1,
       col2
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         LISTAGG(col2, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col2) OVER (PARTITION BY col1)
           AS c2s
  FROM   tbl t
)
GROUP BY col2, c2s
ORDER BY col1, c2s, col2;
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

| COL1 | COL2 |
| --- | --- |
| A,C | 1 |
| A,C | 2 |
| A,C | 3 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nzacmTKz)